# How to understand optimal Scaling in R: The Package homals for novices

Tags: r, pca, spss, ordinal-data, optimal-scaling

Does anyone know of a step-by-step guide for the practical implementation of Gifi Methods for Optimal Scaling in R: The Package homals? Although I have an OK theoretical understanding (thanks chl for directing me to articles), I'm a tech novice and some of the language/technical information is a bit too complicated for me. On that note, can I do the same thing within SPSS??

Answer (score 3):

With regards to SPSS, I believe you need the [Categories add-on module](http://www.spss.com/software/statistics/categories/).

- [SPSS White Paper](ftp://ftp.spss.com/pub/web/wp/SWPOPT.pdf) has further information including lots of references.
- [PPT presentation](http://www.ccsr.ac.uk/methods/festival2004/programme/Thu/am/JCR/documents/Bell_000.ppt) by Richard Bell

Answer (score 2):

Check out homals [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/homals/vignettes/homals.pdf).

Comment: (+1) Thanks for reiterating the need to read the R vignette. Nothing's missing there. And for a more thorough understanding of it, all preprint/draft papers that sit on Jan's website, http://gifi.stat.ucla.edu/

Comment: @chl Yeach, infamous Cuddy Valley...